# Authentication scenario for a combination of ASP.NET Views and SPAs

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 website. It's a portal. Some pages are served by ASP MVC Views, other pages redirect to Angular SPAs.

Some views of the ASP.NET site and some Angular apps need to be behind username/password.

For Angular SPAs it makes sense to use JWT authentication. There is a login component that makes and API call, gets back a JWT token and stores it in the local storage. This works because the JwtBearer scheme was used in ASP.NET for authentication. But once I authenticated with JWT, how do I make plain (not-SPA) ASP.NET Views/Routes respect that JWT token?

Is there a way to force browsers to automatically append the Authorization header based on a Jwt token?

Is that possible to use cookie-based authentication in .NET along side of Jwt authentication?

Is there another way?

Thanks.